# How can I get UIScrollView paging by finger?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have 5 views (view 1, view 2, view 3, view 4, view 5) in a UIScrollView that are snapped to by finger swipes.

**Problem:** If I set pagingEnable = YES, I can't scroll more than 1 View. When I set pagingEnable = NO, scroll didn't centered current view.

**Task:** I need to control a scroll through all views by my finger and

- if I tap on view
- if I stop scrolling
- if scroll stops by himself
  I need current view centered like if pagingEnable was YES.

I found this answers, but it did not really help.

[PagingEnabled for multiple pages in UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580515/pagingenabled-for-multiple-pages-in-uiscrollview)

[How can I let UIScrollView (pagingEnabled) to move 1.2 page each time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350926/how-can-i-let-uiscrollview-pagingenabled-to-move-1-2-page-each-time)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at implementing the delegate callback for:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
  *targetContentOffset = // calculate the required offset to have the scrollview centered
}
```